# Multi page form PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a page which is sending the variable idClient to another page.

Lets say on the step1.php i fill the idClient input and submit it via GET.

It goes to step2.php?idClient=1, then i'am hidding it:

```
<input type="hidden" id="idClient" value="<?php echo $_GET['idClient']; ?>">
```

But after that, when i submit that second page to another, it doesn't send the idClient variable.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="idClient" name="idClient" value="<?php echo $_GET['idClient']; ?>">
```

use `POST` to access **idClient**

Answer (score 2):

You have to change `id="idClient"` to `name="idClient"`.

`id` attribute is only used in the client side, and will never passed to the server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="idClient" name="idClient" value="<?php echo $_GET['idClient']; ?>">
```